# How do I check if the data received from local storage or axios request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, local-storage

I am limited with API calls,
I have the data at the local storage but dont know if it was used and not the API call?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using chrome you can see using the network tab if a call was made to an external api. just open chrome developer tools and see the nwtwork tab at the top. It will show any external requests made